# Phalcon Micro - route with blank parameter

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, phalcon

I have a nginx + phalcon3.3 + php7 server and a script with phalconMicro, in the next route I'm setting:

```
$app->get(
    "/{animal}",
    function ($animal) {
        $REQUEST_URI = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

        echo "$REQUEST_URI<br/>";
        echo "animal: $animal";
        if($animal === ''){
            echo '<br/>No animal, :(';
        }
    }
);
```

Requesting http://localhost:81/cat/dog/bird I get:

```
animals/cat/dog/bird
animal:
No animal, :(
```

I'm trying to get:

```
animals/cat/dog/bird
animal: cat
```

What is my mistake I already eat the phalcon micro tutorial, the phalcon micro api doc and also the nginx + phalcon docs.

btw there is my nginx rule:

```
location ~ /animals {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME thePhalconMicroScript.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your nginx like this:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.3/webserver-setup#nginx

Comment: 1° `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info` is a default also I already got this value int php scope
2° `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is forced to point to an specific script so no 404 rule needed

In the end I give up using phalcon and implement the feature with php vanilla